# ROLLBACK в транзакции выкидывает ошибку - Transact SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

при выполнении кода

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO Foo DEFAULT VALUES
    DECLARE @foo int = 0;
    IF (@foo = 0)
        ROLLBACK;
COMMIT;
```

возникает ошибка:

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Так ошибки нет:

```
   BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        SAVE TRANSACTION firstPoint
        INSERT INTO Foo DEFAULT VALUES
        DECLARE @foo int = 0;
        IF (@foo = 0)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION firstPoint;
   COMMIT;
```

В чём причина? Хотелось бы сделать без точки восстановления

Comment: Во втором случае откат транзакции неполный (до точки), поэтому последующий `commit` возможен. В первом - откат полный, поэтому последующий `commit` невозможен (без открытия новой транзакции).

Answer (score 4):

Причина в том, что нельзя сделать COMMIT несуществующей транзакции, а она будет несуществующей в случае, если условие if сработало и транзакция откатилась.
Поэтому вам нужно делать COMMIT только тогда, когда транзакция существует, например так:

```
IF (@foo = 0)
    ROLLBACK;
ELSE
    COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по коду, у тебя никогда не срабатывает COMMIT, поскольку условие IF (@foo = 0) всегда истинно, и ROLLBACK закрывает открытую транзакцию.